# How do I make an HTTP server that can handle MIME types as well as responses and requests?

Tags: html, node.js, http, mime-types

I'm setting up an HTTP server with NodeJS. I am using the npm module, http-server right now. It handles MIME types perfectly. However, I cannot modify what the server needs to do with certain files. I have one file that requires further action after the requested file has been sent. Are there any modules that allow me to handle requests and be able to handle all MIME types? If so, how do I configure it to?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which HTTP server?

Comment: @al76 — They said in the second sentence of the question. https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Comment: What do you mean by "handle all MIME types"? Can you provide more detail on "requires further action after the requested file has been sent"?

Comment: I want to send an email using the node module, nodemailer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I am using the module, node-static to serve static webpages using nodeJS's http module. I could handle the requests in a function parameter after loading node-static:

```
var http = require('http');

var nStatic = require('node-static');

   var fileServer = new nStatic.Server('./');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fileServer.serve(req, res, (err, response) => {
   // handle requests here (respond with response, not res)
}
}).listen(80);
```